# How to to automate user management on the account with feature set A?

Tags: sap-business-technology-platform

we are currently using SAP BTP with global account with feature set A and are wondering - is there a way to automate user management there, creation, deletion of users etc. So far, we can do it only manually through the Cockpit UI. Found out about [BTP CLI](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/cp-sapcp-getstarted.html), but that one seems to work only on Feature set B. Is there some alternative for Feature set A accounts?

Answer (score 1):

SAP BTP supports to use your Corporate Identity Provider for Platform Users [Feature Set A] as described here:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/783ff50aa60a4c488f4a1e4dceee7ab9.html